# SQL Sum count based on an identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sum

Assume I have a table with the following data:

```
Name          TransID    Cost    
---------------------------------------
 Susan          1        10      
 Johnny         2        10      
 Johnny         3        9      
 Dave           4        10
```

I want to find a way to sum the Costs per name (assume the Names are unique) so that I get a table like this:

```
Name           Cost    
---------------------------------------
 Susan          10     
 Johnny         19        
 Dave           10
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is relatively straightforward: you need to use a [`GROUP BY` clause](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/group_by.php) in your query:

```
SELECT Name,SUM(Cost)
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY Name
```

Comment: I didn't think the group by would keep them separate. Thanks!